# UIScrollView jumps down when first touched

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have two UIScrollViews, one horizontal, one vertical, both two pages each (as in, the horizontal one is two pages wide, and the vertical one is two pages high). The horizontal scrollview is in the vertical one. I am trying to imitate Calcbot's design, where you can scroll left/right for buttons and up/down for history.

However, when the view loads, the horizontal scroll view is about 100 pixels higher than where it should be. Then, when I touch it and begin moving it a little, it jumps/skips down to the correct position and stays there. How do I have it appear correctly right from the start?

Here is my code for viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
horizontalScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
verticalScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;


horizontalScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(horizontalScrollView.bounds.size.width * 2, horizontalScrollView.bounds.size.height); // 2 pages wide.
verticalScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(verticalScrollView.bounds.size.width, verticalScrollView.bounds.size.height * 2);


horizontalScrollView.delegate = self;
verticalScrollView.delegate = self;




[verticalScrollView addSubview:horizontalScrollView];

[verticalScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 640)];

[self.view addSubview:verticalScrollView];

horizontalScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 540, 320, 460);

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jumping in UIScrollView usually happens when you have set pagingEnabled = YES and the contentOffset is set to a position which is not on a page boundry (dividable by bounds.size.height).

Comment: I just changed the contentOffset to 380 and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: In a slightly different scenario, this fixed my jumping issue, too. I had a vertically-only UIScrollView with pagingEnabled from some testing I was doing earlier. Whenever I scrolled down and then tapped anywhere, it would jump back up. Toggled it back off, and all was well.

Comment: Hey @patridge Can you please explain your comment.. I am having similar issue.

Comment: @Mystery it's been a few years, but I'm guessing I had to shut off pagingEnabled as well, even though I didn't have a nested UIScrollView and wasn't setting contentOffset manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought because I am currently messing with UIScrollView too. You could try using `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`. E.g. I set my min and max scrolling in that method because it depends on the size of the content which, from what I read, isn't set until viewWillAppear.

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried this, and it doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Move this line

```
horizontalScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 540, 320, 460);
```

In `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`, see if it works

Comment: Unfortunately, it still appears higher than it should be. Thank you for the suggestion, though.